# F# RProvider rworldmap joinCountryData2Map field, constructor or member 'joinCountryData2Map' is not defined

Tags: r, f#, type-providers

I am playing with F# RProvider and I am unable to make library plugin work. Rworldmap seems to be loaded successfully but F# doesn't recognize related functions like joinCountryData2Map.

I am trying code from Mathias Brandewinder blog - [Creating maps using R, Deedle and F# type providers](http://brandewinder.com/2014/04/12/maps-with-r-deedle-and-fsharp-type-providers/)

I open these namespaces:

```
open FSharp.Data
open RProvider
open RProvider.``base``
open Deedle
open Deedle.RPlugin
open RProvider.rworldmap
```

So far all good. No errors. When I try to run this code:

```
let map = R.joinCountryData2Map(df,"ISO3","Codes")
R.mapCountryData(map,"Pop2000")
```

I get this error:

```
error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'joinCountryData2Map' is not defined.
```

I am not sure if I am missing some library / namespace which needs to be loaded as I am able to use rworldmap directly in R studio without any issues.

Comment: Do you get intellisense for `joinCountryData2Map` or you only get an error during compilation.

Comment: @Michal do you run an app, or in fsi?

Comment: @GeneBelitski I am running in fsi

Comment: @s952163 No I don't intellisense for joinCountryData2Map

Comment: @Michal: try adding to your script `#r "....RProvider.Runtime.dll"` from the same directory where your `RProvider.dll` reside. If this does not help, then perhaps your `RStudio` points to another R environment, than `R Provider`.

Comment: Thanks @GeneBelitski unfortunately I have this already referenced:
#r @"R.NET.Community/lib/net40/RDotNet.dll"
#r @"RProvider/lib/net40/RProvider.Runtime.dll"
#r @"RProvider/lib/net40/RProvider.dll"
#r @"Deedle.RPlugin/lib/net40/Deedle.RProvider.Plugin.dll"

Comment: @Michal Then as the last resort I'd try running your script in a fresh environment prepending `open RProvider.rworldmap` with the following line: `RProvider.utils.R.install_packages(["rworldmap"])`.

Comment: Are you actually referencing the correct path though for the libraries, they usually go into a packages folder. I would also try something simple, like adding two numbers or creating an array in R. btw are you using 64-bit R and 64-bit FSI?

Comment: @s952163 I am running under Visual Studio Code which is 64b but to be sure I have rather installed rworldmap under both 64 and 32 bit R studio. Path to libs is correct I have used #I @".." directive at the beginning of script. Also I am able to plot some histogram and other simple things, problem is only wordlmap.

Comment: @GeneBelitski I have tried to install it from F#, all went fine but problem remains:
RProvider.utils.R.install_packages(["rworldmap"])
- ;;
trying URL 'https://mirrors.nic.cz/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/rworldmap_1.3-6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2872610 bytes (2.7 MB)
downloaded 2.7 MB

package 'rworldmap' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

Comment: Maybe you should ping mathias in the #datascience channel on the [F# Slack](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/). Than you could check what is different between the environments.